# Positioning .inlineshapes/shapes in MS word?

Tags: ms-word, vb6, report

I'm trying to place a logo near the text in the header. I'm able to resize it. However, I'm having a very difficult time positionining it anywhere (preferaby LEFT and TOP) would work. here is the code I have. It dumps the image far int he left top corner and I have no idea how to move it. Do I have to convert it to shape before being able to move it?

Dim SHP As InlineShape
   'Dim SHP As Shape

```
With w_Wrd.Selection
    .Font.Reset
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 14
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .TypeText " Needs Assessment/Family Care Plan NA/FCP "
End With
   Set SHP = w_Wrd.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="Q:\IS\CEDAR\letetrhead.png", _
                        LinkToFile:=False, _
                        SaveWithDocument:=True)

    With SHP
        .Height = InchesToPoints(0.8)
        .Width = InchesToPoints(1.3)
        .ConvertToShape
    End With
```

Comment: This is really the same question as the other one, I posted a comment to a few minutes ago? Although you seem to have progressed a step since then. But still, I don't think you need both questions...?

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm trying to get someone to help me. I progressed a step and now I'm stuck again.